# the "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Overflowed precision" error on fetch oracle data in Python with PySpark and JDBC Driver

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, pyspark, ojdbc

I tried to connect to oracle database by spark technology, PySpark tool.
spark 1.5 ,scala-2.10.4 ,Pyhton3.4, ojdbc7.jar
I did not install oracle client,only copied oracle library and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
I tested,worked correctly and could fetch data with os(Centos 7)Also R(with ROracle Package) and Python3.4(with cx_Oracle).
I used below connection in PySpark:

```
df=sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:oracle:thin:UserName/Password@IP:1521/SID',dbtable="Table").load()
```

It connect with no problem but when i tried to df.head() for example I faced this error

```
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 2 (showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2) with 1 output partitions
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 2(showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 2 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2), which has no missing parents
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(5872) called with curMem=17325, maxMem=13335873454
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 5.7 KB, free 12.4 GB)
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2789) called with curMem=23197, maxMem=13335873454
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.7 KB, free 12.4 GB)
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on localhost:41646 (size: 2.7 KB, free: 12.4 GB)
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:861
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from ResultStage 2 (MapPartitionsRDD[5] at showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2)
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 2.0 with 1 tasks
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1929 bytes)
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
15/12/03 16:41:52 INFO JDBCRDD: closed connection
15/12/03 16:41:52 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Overflowed precision
...
```

as I searched I found it was bug that solved in *github* and should be solved by below code line

```
case java.sql.Types.NUMERIC       => DecimalType.bounded(precision + scala, scale)
```

but as I checked that exist in my  JDBCRDD.scala file.

is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had negotiate whit one of Spark developer and he told this is a bug and we should wait for new version or use jira spark version.